# form_with is trying to generate the action with the wrong path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm experimenting with routing and namespaces.

When implementing a form with `<%= form_with model: [@user, @address] do |form| %>`
i receive this error `undefined method 'customer_user_customer_addresses_path'`

This is the routing schema

```
  namespace :customer do
    resources :users do
      resource :contact
      resources :addresses
    end
  end

  resolve('Customer::Contact') {
    [:customer, :user, :contact]
  }
```

All routes printed by `rails routes` command are as expected.

```
                 customer_user_addresses GET    /customer/users/:user_id/addresses(.:format)                                                      customer/addresses#index
                                         POST   /customer/users/:user_id/addresses(.:format)                                                      customer/addresses#create
               new_customer_user_address GET    /customer/users/:user_id/addresses/new(.:format)                                                  customer/addresses#new
              edit_customer_user_address GET    /customer/users/:user_id/addresses/:id/edit(.:format)                                             customer/addresses#edit
                   customer_user_address GET    /customer/users/:user_id/addresses/:id(.:format)                                                  customer/addresses#show
                                         PATCH  /customer/users/:user_id/addresses/:id(.:format)                                                  customer/addresses#update
                                         PUT    /customer/users/:user_id/addresses/:id(.:format)                                                  customer/addresses#update
                                         DELETE /customer/users/:user_id/addresses/:id(.:format)                                                  customer/addresses#destroy
```

## This is what i was able to do

- by creating the `Customer::UsersController` i was able to access all crud operations for the users resources
- by creating the `Customer::ContactsController` i was able to access all crud operations but i had to add the resolve directive in order to make the routes generated correctly

```
  resolve('Customer::Contact') {
    [:customer, :user, :contact]
  }
```

## This is where i'm in trouble

When implementing the `Customer::AddressesController` i can't figure out a way to make form_with requesting the correct path.

This is the controller action

```
  def new
    @breadcrumbs = []
    @user = Customer::User.find(params[:user_id])
    @address = @user.addresses.build
  end
```

This is the new template

```
<%= form_with model: [@user, @address] do |form| %>
```

When i navigate to the new action i get this error `undefined method 'customer_user_customer_addresses_path'`

In order to make it working i had to pass an url parameter with the correct path: `<%= form_with model: [@user, @address], url: customer_user_addresses_path(@user) do |form| %>`.

What convention am i missing? is there any way to omit the url parameter?

## Info

Repository: https://github.com/LuigiDeCosmis/GestionaleTest

Template to check is under customer/addresses/new.html.erb

Comment: Can you show console output after `rails routes` with customer_user_addresses_path?

Comment: I've updated my question by adding the generated controller routes

Comment: while it's address creation then why not just use `form_with model: @address, url: customer_user_addresses_path(user_id: @user.id)`?

Comment: i'm learning how routing works, and i want to see what can rails automatically do for me, or what i should change in order to take advantage of the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Where did `customer_` prefix come from?**

You are getting `customer_` prefix both for `user` and `address` in your error message

```
undefined method 'customer_user_customer_addresses_path'
```

because you are trying to build you path based on models - while both  of your `User` / `Address` models are placed in `Customer` namespace.

To be specific - `customer_` prefix came from here:

```rb
Customer::User.model_name.param_key
# => "customer_user"
Customer::Address.model_name.param_key
# => "customer_address"
```

This is how it's trying to parse it:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/af773ae44a1ae465cc0d19b1e8bf3fc731221ef0/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L756

**What convention am i missing?**

I can see no reason why you should namespace your models like that.

If you want your users to be either `customer` / `admin` or anything else - you should rather use STI approach

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html

https://medium.com/nyc-ruby-on-rails/single-table-inheritance-sti-ruby-on-rails-basics-2a08c81e50af

**Is there any way to omit the url parameter?**

Yes. After you get rid of `Customer` namespace for models you will be able to see in your routes something like:

```
customer_user_addresses
```

This is an example of routes which can be set up with model option.

Hope that helps! Good luck!

Comment: by adding the `customer` namespace the error changes in `undefined method 'customer_customer_user_customer_addresses_path'`. I can't figure out why it appends customer_ on all models

Comment: It appends `customer` because you use `namespace` in your `routes.rb`.
Please try to replace it with `scope` - then your controllers will stay namespaced with `Customer::` but your routes will be kind of `user_addresses_path` and your initial `form_with model: [@user, @address]` will do the job.

Comment: Or even `scope :customer, module: :customer` (for your `Customer::` contollers to be looked up).

Comment: By swapping `namespace :customer do` with `scope :customer, module: :customer do` as you said route name changed but this error `undefined method 'customer_user_customer_addresses_path'` is still present.

Comment: Could you pls provide github repo link we could reproduce symptom with?

Comment: Here is what I see:
https://gist.github.com/peresvetjke/884f76f6506b8907485398f90fc5cef6

Comment: I have updated the question with the repository link

Comment: Thanks now i finally got it how this name is generated. I will try with STI seems the right fit for my needs. One last thing, so if someone wants to still use that namespace like modeling he has to specify manually the url in order to make it work.

Comment: Yes, if you have nested namespaced models and want to get form_with working - you should be able to do it with url param.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error, specify the URL explicitly in your form_with helper:

```rb
<%= form_with(model: [@user, @address], url: customer_user_addresses_path(@user)) do |form| %>
```

Alternatively, ensure your routes match the nesting structure:

```rb
namespace :customer do
  resources :users do
    resources :addresses
  end
end
```

Then, you can use form_with without specifying the URL:

```rb
<%= form_with(model: [:customer, @user, @address]) do |form| %>
```

The issue you're encountering with the route generation appending "customer_" to the path suggests a problem with how Rails is interpreting the namespace in your routes.

It seems like Rails is treating "customer" as a singular resource instead of correctly understanding it as a namespace. This can happen if Rails isn't recognizing the namespace due to how it's defined or how the routes are being generated.

To fix this, ensure that you're correctly defining the namespace in your routes. It should be pluralized and nested within the namespace method:

```rb
namespace :customer do
  resources :users do
    resources :addresses
  end
end
```

Make sure you've pluralized "customer" in your controllers, models, and views consistently. For example, you should have a `Customer::UsersController`, not `Customer::UserController`.

If the issue persists, try restarting your Rails server to ensure that any changes to the routes file are being picked up correctly. If the problem still exists, there may be a deeper issue with how your routes or namespaces are configured.

By following these steps and ensuring consistency in naming and configuration, you should be able to resolve the issue with the route generation.

Comment: - The routes declaration is written with the correct namespace and pluralized resources.
- The controller names are also pluralized